# when consider all the indirect effects

Tags: word-usage

Which is more natural in English? "when considering all the indirect effects" or "when consider all the indirect effects"?

> Those are some pretty sobering statistics – and they indicate that a true solution to hearing problem is needed now.And the problem gets worse **when consider all the indirect effects** that are associated with hearing loss.

> Source: (Advertorial) [Hearing Enhancers Revolution in The USA New Device Slashes Prices by over 90%](https://secure.aidion.com/livehealthy-v6/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMItITBmsne7gIVngetBh14sgj4EAEYASAAEgIJ-vD_BwE)

Comment: That web site is pure comedy: thanks for sharing. The english is awful: I found ten mistakes, before I stopped looking. The maths is even worse: "... over 5% of the world's population – which is basically one in every ten people ... ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first phrase is natural: *When considering all the indirect effects...*. This is because *When consider all...* is not grammatical. The adverb *when* introduces a phrase, and if you use a verb there, it needs to be a gerund (-ing).